# Using inner join on two tables with foreign key that references primary id on main table

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have the following tables:

BrandsTable

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID        | varchar(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| CarBrand  | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| FuelType  | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

ModelsTable

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID         | int(2)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Model      | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| BrandID    | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| TopSpeed   | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Here are some entries

```
+----+----------------+-------------------------+
| ID | CarBrand       | FuelType                |
+----+----------------+-------------------------+
| 0  | Ford           | Gasoline                |
| 1  | Chevy          | Gasoline                |
| 2  | Peterbilt      | Diesel                  |
| 3  | GMC            | Gasoline                |
| 4  | OshKosh        | Natural Gas             |
+----+----------------+-------------------------+

+----+---------------+---------+------------+
| ID | Model         | BrandID | TopSpeed   |
+----+---------------+---------+------------+
|  1 | F150          | 0       | 130MPH     |
|  2 | 1500          | 1       | 110MPH     |
|  3 | 389           | 2       | 70MPH      |
|  4 | 1500          | 3       | 110MPH     |
|  5 | Mustang       | 0       | 170MPH     |
|  6 | Cement Truck  | 4       | 65MPH      |
+----+---------------+---------+------------+
```

BrandID column in the Models table is the foreign key to the Brand table’s primary key, the ID column. What if you **do not have access** to the values of either of the columns. How would I write an SQL Query that will list all the Models that belong to Ford using INNER JOIN

Comment: What do you mean by `you do not have access to the values of either of the columns`?

Comment: What do you mean by "do not have access" to a column? If either of the columns is not there, you can't do a join at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "What if you do not have access to the values of either of the columns?"

Comment: They are unknown values basically all 0's

Comment: It's weird isn't it that a car manufacturer would restrict themselves to only one fuel type!?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not have access id's , It means that you just have the models names I guess..
so knowing "ford" you can get both ids like this...

```
select * from modelsTable Mod inner join brandsTable Bra
on Mod.id= ( select id from Bra where CarBrand='FORD')
```